# How to show sub-categories in the Categories Dropdown list

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

in my code,i want to show **category** and **sub catagory** under the Category in the **Products table**.

**Here** is my **categories table**

**1.**

```
 public function up() { Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('parent_id'); 
    $table->string('name');  
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

**Here** is my **products table**

**2.**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id');
        $table->string('product_name');
        $table->string('product_code');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Here** is my **Category Model**

**3.Category.php**

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model { protected $guarded=[];

public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

**Here** is my **Product Model**

**4.Product.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function category(){
        return $this->hasone('class::Category');
    }

}
```

Now here is my **ProductsController.php**

**5.ProductsController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Category;
use App\Product;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{

     public function addproduct(Request $request){
         $product=New Product();
         $product->category_id=$request['category_id'];
         $product->product_name=$request['product_name'];
         $product->product_code=$request['product_code'];
         $product->status = request('status');
         $product->save();
         return back()->with('success','product Upload Successfully!');

         }
}
```

Here is my **addproduct.blade.php** file

**6.addproduct.blade.php**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{route('add.product')}}" name="add_product" id="add_product" novalidate="novalidate">
                                @csrf

                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">main Category </label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <select name="category_id" id="category_id" style="width:220px;">

                                            <option value="0">Main Category</option>
                                            @foreach(App\Category::all() as $cat)
                                                <option value="{{$cat->id}}" >{{$cat->name}}</option>
                                            @endforeach

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Product Name</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="text" name="product_name" id="product_name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Product Code</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="text" name="product_code" id="product_code">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Product Color</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="text" name="product_color" id="product_color">
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-actions">
                                    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                                </div>

                            </form>
```

**7. I want to data like this**

Shoe
  --casual shoe
  --formal shoe
Mobile
--Android Mobile
--iphone

Comment: your request is not clear, please write your request as tree

Comment: And what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Category Model

```
class Category extends Model { protected $guarded=[];

    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }

    public function parent(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

In your blade

```
@foreach(App\Category::all() as $cat)
    <option value="{{$cat->id}}" >{{ isset($cat->parent->name) ? $cat->parent->name . ' -- ' : '' }}{{$cat->name}}</option>
@endforeach
```

*Ps: For your development: Blade for viewing codes, You should be use variables in blade not models. So crate variable like this `$categories = Category::all();` and pass to view in index method in Your Controller and use it in blade.*

Comment: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name (View: F:\laragon\www\flipcart\resources\views\admin\products\addproduct.blade.php)

Comment: Please use parent instead of parent() and please check with isset

Comment: @foreach(App\Category::all() as $cat)

                                                <option value="{{$cat->id}}" >
                                                    {{ $cat->parent ? $cat->parent->name . ' -- ' : '' }}
                                                    {{$cat->name}}
                                                </option>

                                            @endforeach

Comment: It 90% works,but in my form My default value should be select ,but it is shown as category value ex:- at first the default value have select,then i select a value

Comment: check with <option value="{{$cat->id}}" @if($loop->index == 0) selected @endif >